# UIButton created in UItableview cell crashes when tapped

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitableview, uibutton

I created a custom UItableviewcell

added a button into its initWithStyle area:

```
favoriteButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
        favoriteButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [favoriteButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [favoriteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(favoriteClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        favoriteButton.center = self.center;
```

set its frame and layout in:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect contentRect = self.contentView.bounds;
    CGFloat boundsX = contentRect.origin.x;
    CGRect frame;

    frame = CGRectMake(boundsX+200, 44, 40, 40);
    favoriteButton.frame = frame;

}
```

and then in my tableviewcontroller.m file I use that tableviewcell and have the user click tap to go to the action within that tableviewcontroller.m code

```
-(void)favoriteClick:(id)sender// forEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    NSLog(@"click");

}
```

however when i tap the button I get an unhandled exception:

```
2010-07-24 16:06:02.197 Film Fest[10342:40b] -[ProgramGuideCell favoriteClick:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e63ff0
2010-07-24 16:06:02.200 Film Fest[10342:40b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ProgramGuideCell favoriteClick:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e63ff0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02a56919 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02ba45de objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02a5842b -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x029c8116 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x029c7cd2 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   UIKit                               0x00301e14 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    6   UIKit                               0x0038b6c8 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x0038db4a -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    8   UIKit                               0x0038c6f7 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    9   UIKit                               0x00579070 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdateObserver + 3687
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x02a37d1b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x029cc987 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x02995c17 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x02995280 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x029951a1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x030b42c8 GSEventRunModal + 217
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x030b438d GSEventRun + 115
    17  UIKit                               0x0030fb58 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    18  Film Fest                           0x00002170 main + 102
    19  Film Fest                           0x00002101 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

I dont see what Im doing wrong here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning `IBAction` instead of `void` on your selector, and put the selector in the `ProgramGuideCell` instead of tableviewcontroller.

```
-(IBAction)favoriteClick:(id)sender// forEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    NSLog(@"click");

}
```

Comment: nope no luck there. still crashes.  I made sure to modify the h file and the m file, also the cell is programmatically made so its not really an IBAction context...

Comment: I updated my answer. You should put the selector in the proper class. Otherwise, you need to specify the instance in the selector.